Euler's polyhedron formula modulo 2
Recall that Euler's polyhedron formula states that, for every (orientable) polyhedron with $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, $F$ faces, and $g$ holes (or more formally, with genus $g$),
$$V-E+F=2-2g.$$
As an immediate consequence,
$$V-E+F\equiv0\pmod2,$$
independent of $g$.

Is there  a way to prove the statement $V-E+F\equiv0\pmod2$ without going through the proof of Euler's polyhedron formula? In other words, if we just want Euler's formula modulo $2$, is there an easier proof?


In cube type polyhedrons we always have: $v=2n, E=3n, F=n+2\Rightarrow V-E+F=2\equiv0\bmod 2$. In conic type polyhedrons we always have $V=n+1, E=2n, F=n+1\Rightarrow V-E+F=2\equiv 0 \bmod 2$.

What is your definition of a "polyhedron"? Do you mean a compact surface (without boundary)? Then $\chi$ could be odd.

@MoisheKohan I want orientability!

Then you should revise your question accordingly, you know this... And I think, the simplest proof would go through the classification of surfaces (at least through the point where you identify the boundary of a polygon according to an orientation-preserving word).

@MoisheKohan sorry I thought it was implied by talking about genus since that's usually only defined for orientable surfaces.

No, it is defined in general as the number of components of a maximal nonseparating 1-dimensional submanifold.

It makes no sense to say "orientable polyhedron." What you mean is "compact orientable surface" (your own proof does not use a PL structure).

Here is a high-brow proof. This is equivalent to showing that the Euler characteristic of any compact orientable connected surface $S$ is even. The Euler characteristic is
$$\chi(S)=\dim_{\mathbb Q}H^0(S,\mathbb Q)-\dim_{\mathbb Q}H^1(S,\mathbb Q)+\dim_{\mathbb Q}H^2(S,\mathbb Q).$$
Since $S$ is connected we have $H^0(S,\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Q$, and by Poincaré duality $H^2(S,\mathbb Q)\simeq\mathbb Q$ as well. Thus,
$$\chi(S)=2-\dim_{\mathbb Q}H^1(S,\mathbb Q)$$
and it suffices to show $H^1(S,\mathbb Q)$ has even dimension. The cup product is a non-degenerate symplectic form on $H^1(S,\mathbb Q)$ and its a standard fact that if a finite-dimensional vector space has a non-degenerate symplectic form then it is even-dimensional.

This might be valid , though there are 2 Objections : (1) You were looking for "easier proof" , which this is not. (2) When you are using Euler Characteristic & assuming it is invariant , you are already using the Original formula which you want to avoid.

Knowing the Euler characteristic is invariant does not use the original formula: it is a theorem of algebraic topology that can be formulated and proved without using genus. Of course I agree it is not "easier"!

When we use that theorem of algebraic topology , we will still have to show that this value is the same as that value. We might require the Original formula there. Showing that Equivalence is almost same as Proving/Using that Original formula.

@Prem Not at all. What's required is showing the expression for the Euler characteristic in terms of co/homology agrees with the one in terms of vertices, edges, and faces. This takes some work, sure, but it does in no way involve the fact that $V + F - E = 2g - 2$, which is what Kenta wants to avoid.

Hmmm , "takes some work ... no way involve" : that effort [ + that avoidance ] can be gauged only when we attempt it , @BenSteffan , though it is currently missing. We can not assume it trivially.

@Prem This proof has been attempted many times and brought to completion, because this is a bog standard result from algebraic topology that is treated in pretty much any textbook on the matter. You'll kindly forgive me speaking in deference, you sounded so confident in what you're saying that I assumed you were well on top of the matter. In any case, you can find this as theorem 2.44 in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology." It's quite short and you should have no problem whatsoever verifying that Euler's polyhedron formula is not used (in fact, it is discussed directly afterwards as a corollary).

Oh , thanks for the reference , @BenSteffan , I will check it. I am neither a mathematician by training nor by Profession , so I moistly go with Intuition , which might/will/can go wrong too. I mix up the things I read here & there , so I do not know whether something was given in some order somewhere or whether something will workout or not until I see it at some high-level.

The question was already answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310335/closed-orientable-surfaces-have-even-euler-characteristic
Although the answer deals with simplicial complexes (so all faces are triangles), the general case can be deduced by triangulating each face.

Consider the Simplest Polyhedron : Pyramid with triangular sides.
$V=4,E=6,F=4$ , where $V-E+F=2\equiv 0 \mod 2$
We can make a larger Polyhedron by gluing together 2 Polyhedra along a face.
$V_1-E_1+F_1 \equiv 0 \mod 2$
$V_2-E_2+F_2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$
The new Polyhedron will have all the old vertices , except along the gluing face , where $n$ vertices will be common.
At the same time , there will be all the old edges , except along the gluing face , where $n$ edges will be common.
More-over , there will be all the old faces , except along the gluing face , where $2$ faces will vanish.
$V_3=V_1+V_2-n$
$E_3=E_1+E_2-n$
$F_3=F_1+F_2-2$
$V_3-E_3+F_3 = (V_1+V_2-n) - (E_1+E_2-n) + (F_1+F_2-2) \equiv 0 \mod 2$
The gluing did not introduce holes.
We can glue 2 Polyhedra along multiple faces to introduce holes.
[[ It is equivalent to gluing 2 faces of 2 Polyhedra & then gluing 2 faces of the new Polyhedron ]]
Similar calculations will show that the $\mod 2$ value will not change.
In addition to gluing , there are other operations , like (1) removing one vertex , to make a larger face & (2) removing one edge to join 2 neighboring faces.  Here too , we can easily check that the $\mod 2$ value will not change.
With the , we can generate all Polyhedra with arbitrary $V,E,G,g$ values. Every time , the $\mod 2$ value will not change.
While that completes the Proof , it might be useful (though not necessary) to view the operations.
VIEWING VARIOUS OPERATIONS PICTORIALLY :
Polyhedral glueing :

Edge Elimination :

Vertex Elimination :

Self glueing :

Multiple glueing :

All Cases have invariant $\mod 2$ value.

How do we know that any polyhedron can be constructed by these operations?

Anyway, this looks essentially the same as the proof of Euler's formula.

The Query over "can be constructed" is easy , but laborious , @mr_e_man , it will divert too much from OP Question. All Polyhedra can be triangulated & thus Decomposed with the reversal of the operations listed here. We could reverse that Decomposition to generate all Polyhedra.

The Query over "essentially the same" : guilty as charged , @mr_e_man , OP wants to avoid using genus $g$ which is indeed avoided with my outline : hence it is indeed suitable to the OP Question !
